# Is there a word for this technique? If so, what is it?

Tags: theory

Ive been recently listening to kpop and i came across this song that piqued my interest:

At 1:06 the pitch goes down and it sounds nice, to me at least.
Is there a name for this?

Comment: Are you talking about the bass that seems to "drag" and drop in pitch?

Answer (score 1):

It's a chromatic shift downwards, from G#m through Gm into F#m. A Beatles song Listen, do you want to know a Secret' does a similar thing. Same key too, I think...